# Определить referer и текущий урл

Tags: php, javascript

Есть js код который генерируется скриптом на одном домене и запускается на другом. Мне нужно в этом скрипте определить рефер если и есть и текущий урл сайта на котором этот скрипт запустился.

На js это сделать не проблема, но нужно еще передать эту информацию в php обработчик моего скрипта, хотел это сделать через ajax но политика конфиденциальности не позволяет потому что домены различаются. А если через $_SERVER переменные попытаться взять информацию то получаем данные о том домене на котором располагается скрипт...

Как же получить нужную информацию о сайте на котором запускается этот скрипт  и передать его в обработчик ?

Comment: [XSS?][1]

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Comment: CORS, но надо чтобы домен на котором PHP был под вашим контролем.

Comment: CORS помог, добавил в заголовок 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
теперь все нормально работает